# Safe Way To Loop PDO Statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Question:

Loop through a prepared PDO statement, check for duplicates, if no duplicates execute the query?

Current PDO Statement:

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO inbox (id,efrom,subject,msg,eread,date) VALUES ('',:efrom,:esubject,:emsg,:eread,:edate)");
$STH->bindParam(':efrom', $inbox_from[0]);
$STH->bindParam(':esubject', $inbox_subject[0]);
$STH->bindParam(':emsg', $inbox_msg[0]);
$STH->bindParam(':eread', $inbox_read[0]);
$STH->bindParam(':edate', $inbox_date[0]);
```

Why there needs to be a loop:

I need the arrays `$inbox_*` to be incremented then queried until it gets to the end of the array.

Example:

```
$inbox_from('hello','how','are','you');

someloop(somecondition) {
    //output would be:
    $STH->bindParam(':efrom', $inbox_from[0]);
    $STH->bindParam(':efrom', $inbox_from[1]);
    $STH->bindParam(':efrom', $inbox_from[2]);
    $STH->bindParam(':efrom', $inbox_from[3]);
    //It ends at [3] index because its the end of the array.
}
$STH = execute();
//So now it executes and should have put the 4 array indexes into different efrom columns. So column id 1 has 'hello' and id 4 has 'you'.
```

Maybe:

```
for($i = 0; //Something to check if array ended; ++$i) {
//Someway to Properly bind the arrays and execute?
}
```

or some use of a While Loop?

Hope I explained it my best.

#### Whats the best practice to use here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use numbered parameters instead of named parameters, and build the query and parameters dynamically.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO inbox (efrom,subject,msg,eread,date) VALUES ";
// array_fill will create an array of N "(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" strings
// implode will then join them together with comma separators
$sql .= implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($inbox_from), "(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"));
$STH = $DBH->prepare($sql);
$params = array();
// Populate the $params array with all the input values
foreach ($inbox_from as $i => $from) {
    $params[] = $from;
    $params[] = $inbox_subject[$i];
    $params[] = $inbox_msg[$i];
    $params[] = $inbox_read[$i];
    $params[] = $inbox_date[$i];
}
$STH->execute($params);
```

You can leave the `id` field out of the column list, and it will be filled in automatically using auto-increment.

To remove duplicate messages, you can do:

```
$check_stmt = $DBH->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM inbox WHERE msg = :msg");
$check_stmt->bindParam(':msg', $msg);
$messages_seen = array();
foreach ($inbox_msg as $i => $msg) {
    // Check if the message is already in the DB
    $check_stmt->execute();
    $first_row = $check_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $check_stmt->fetchAll(); // Fetch the rest of the query to get in sync
    if ($first_row->count > 0) {
        $messages_seen[$msg] = true; // Remember that we already saw this message
    } elseif (!isset($messages_seen[$msg])) // If we haven't already seen this message
        $params[] = $inbox_from[$i];
        $params[] = $inbox_subject[$i];
        $params[] = $msg;
        $params[] = $inbox_read[$i];
        $params[] = $inbox_date[$i];
        $messages_seen[$msg] = true; // Remember that we added this message
    }
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO inbox (efrom,subject,msg,eread,date) VALUES ";
// There's 1 (...) group for every 5 parameters, so divide the length of $params by 5 to know how many of them to put in the SQL
$sql .= implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($params)/5, "(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"));
$STH = $DBH->prepare($sql);
$STH->execute($params);
```

When adding an index on a TEXT datatype, you have to specify the number of bytes of the text to store in the index. So it should be something like:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_msg ON inbox (msg(200));
```

Comment: Before I test this, May you please use // comment tags to explain each line for me?

Comment: I've added some comments

Comment: Works wonders! May I ask how I can stop duplicates from being inserted, Like if the Message is already is the msg column anywhere then stop it from inserting ANYTHING for that row as in skip that specific $i loop?

Comment: Im trying to add a Unique Key to Message, It works kind of, If any of the loops try to insert and only one of them are a duplicate none of the loops work. Anyway to fix this?

Comment: Use `INSERT IGNORE` so it skips duplicates instead of causing an error.

Comment: Im trying to add that but its saying:  column 'msg' used in key specification without a key length

Comment: Is `msg` a `TEXT` type? You need to change it to `VARCHAR` so you can put a unique index on it.

Comment: Well, Yes its specifically a LONGTEXT because the MSG column will contain HTML and who knows how big it could be. Varchar is quite small, Anyway around it?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to skip duplicates when creating the parameters.

Comment: Not sure how exactly this is working. Can you please comment it?

Comment: What part of it isn't obvious? Dividing the length of `$params` by 5? Using an associative array to check for duplicates?

Comment: Well what in the query is actually saying theres a duplicate or not, To me it seems like its just adding a duplicate email into the array while stating true, Then just like in your last example adding the $params to the Database. Not sure wat dividing the $params variable by 5 would do.

Comment: It only adds to `$params` if it doesn't find it already in `$messages_seen`.

Comment: I divide `count($params)` by 5 because there's one `(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)` group for every 5 parameters.

Comment: Ahh yes, DIdn't spot the if (), Thats all good and WOULD work but in my case it wont as the loop wont get duplicates, Like basically I want it to **skip** that specific the loop to actually loop if the $msg is already in any row inside the database. Not inside the loop. See what im saying?

Comment: Would I need to open a second PDO connection just to use to search from?

Comment: No. You can reuse the same PDO connection for all the queries.

Comment: Ok then whats the best query to use here? And how would I execute it efficiently per loop?

Comment: Best query for what? If you have a different question, post a new question, don't ask it in the comment section. But you should also do some searching, because there are lots of other questions about how to generate dynamic search queries.

Comment: No like what I mean is where would I post a simple SELECT query in this script? Like inside of the loop somewhere or?

Comment: Oh, I missed that part of your above comment. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Okay, I see how this is working. Wouldnt it be better to do:
`if ($check_stmt->execute()->fetch_obj()->count = 0) {
 $params[] = $inbox_from[$i];
 $params[] = $inbox_subject[$i];
 $params[] = $msg;
 $params[] = $inbox_read[$i];
 $params[] = $inbox_date[$i];
}`
Since the $messages_seen[$msg] = true; doesnt really do anything and wouldnt be needed.

Comment: That will detect duplicates that are already in the database, but it won't detect if two elements of `$inbox_msg` have duplicate messages.

Comment: I suppose, But due to the environment of how inbox_msg is made it wont really be needed in my case.

Comment: OK, then you can do it your way.

Comment: [06-Oct-2015 15:21:51 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch_obj() on boolean in /home/unfed/public_html/admin/global/cron.php on line 83

Comment: Also I put $check_stmt->bindParam(':msg', $msg); inside the loop because $msg is made inside the loop from the condition.

Comment: That's not necessary. `bindParam` binds to a reference, so you only have to do it once, it will use the updated value of the variable.

Comment: Oops, `fetch_obj` is mysqli, I fixed it for PDO.

Comment: Still seem to be getting this Member function error

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, `execute()` doesn't return the statement, so it can't be chained like that. I splilt it into separate statements.

Comment: New error: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active.  Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll().  Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.' in /home/unfed/public_html/admin/global/cron.php:98

Comment: I'm not sure why that's an issue, since the query only returns one row, but I'll fix the code.

Comment: Another error xD PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1' in /home/unfed/public_html/admin/global/cron.php:100

Comment: Line 100 is $STH = $DBH->prepare($sql);

Comment: Make sure the `$params` array isn't empty before trying to do the query.

Comment: Yes, Apparently its empty. Not sure why.

Comment: Maybe all the messages are duplicates?

Comment: Fixed, I had my condition as: if ($first_row->count = 0) { but it should be if ($first_row->count == '0') { so that if theres no duplicates it will output. Why im doing this condition is to just completely skip $message_seen stuff. In my opinion its really unnecessary as if theres a duplicate in the $msg it wont be inserted anyway so its not really sparing time.

Comment: Yeah, that's fine if there can't be duplicates in $inbox_msg

Answer (score 0):

You can create one big query if you are using Insert to same table

```
INSERT INTO table (columns) VALUES (....), (....)...., (...)
```

Its better than calling to sql for each row.  Faster too

Comment: Yes but not on the same row and I dont know how many indexes is actually in the array which is why we need to use some while loop or something.

Comment: No need to know..  Build your query with implode() method.